# Pushing Rails app to heroku gives me Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a Rails 7.x app I am trying to push to heroku and getting this error:

```
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        Compiling...
remote:        Compilation failed:
remote:        node:internal/crypto/hash:71
remote:          this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);
remote:                          ^
remote:
remote:        Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
remote:            at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
remote:            at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
remote:            at module.exports (/tmp/build_b1f32be4/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:135:53)
remote:            at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/tmp/build_b1f32be4/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:417:16)
remote:            at handleParseError (/tmp/build_b1f32be4/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:471:10)
remote:            at /tmp/build_b1f32be4/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:503:5
remote:            at /tmp/build_b1f32be4/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:358:12
remote:            at /tmp/build_b1f32be4/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:373:3
remote:            at iterateNormalLoaders (/tmp/build_b1f32be4/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
remote:            at iterateNormalLoaders (/tmp/build_b1f32be4/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
remote:            at /tmp/build_b1f32be4/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:236:3
remote:            at context.callback (/tmp/build_b1f32be4/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
remote:            at /tmp/build_b1f32be4/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:44:71 {
remote:          opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
remote:          library: 'digital envelope routines',
remote:          reason: 'unsupported',
remote:          code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
remote:        }
remote:
remote:        Node.js v18.12.1
remote:
remote:
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
```

My node version locally is `v18.12.1`. I also saw a couple of issues where this might related to openssl. My openssl version local is `OpenSSL 3.0.7 1 Nov 2022 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.7 1 Nov 2022)`.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: This appears to be the same issue https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/14532, but running `export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider` locally does nothing to change the deploy on heroku.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I tried quite a few things in attempts to fix this issue, but I think what finally did it was adding

```
 "engines": {
    "node": "16.18.1"
  }
```

...to my package.json file. Also I think the right way to do this is to go ahead and install the same version of node locally and re-run `yarn install` so your `yarn.lock` file is correct for that version.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Saved my life, man. Finally got into installing `nvm` on Windows on my local machine because I literally have to run a lower version of node just to run webpack on Rails.

Comment: Thank You, I spend hours last night trying to make this work, only coming back to this today it helped me.

Answer (score 0):

[Heroku suggests](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version) defining which version of node you want to use for your project

It's a good idea to [use an LTS version](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/error-error-0308010c-digital-envelope-routines-unsupported-node-error-solved/) of node.

Switching to 16.16.0 solved my problem